# Not able to write to a file

Tags: c++

My programs have been running properly for over a year. Today I copied the files onto a different system and compiled every program.

When I compile and run from Dev-c++ it writes data onto a text file like its supposed to, but when I click on the executable it creates, it does not write data onto the file. Everything else like input/output seems to work.

What procedure have I missed?

Ok i've given the program Full permision but it still does not write.

I'm quite puzzled, atleast if it didn't run when i compile it in the C++ environment i can keep checking my code, but only the .exe does not work, any other suggestions ?

```
 #include <iostream> 
 #include <fstream>
 using namespace std; 
 int main() {  
 ofstream bss2; 
 bss2.open("expat.txt",ios::app);
 bss2 << 2 ; 
 bss2.close();
 }
```

This is the sample code i tested out.

How do i find the Current working directory ?

Ok i changed a line to

```
bss2.open("c:\\expat2.txt",ios::app);
```

and now it works properly in the exe file.

but there's over 50 files and i prefer i didn't have to spell out the new path to each one, what workaround is there to set the directory to the one previously used ?

update 4 :

```
 #define _POSIX_SOURCE
 #include <unistd.h>
 #undef _POSIX_SOURCE
 #include <stdio.h>

 main() {
   char cwd[256];
   int y;
   if (chdir("/tmp") != 0)
     perror("chdir() error()");
   else {
     if (getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)) == NULL)
       perror("getcwd() error");
     else
       printf("current working directory is: %s\n", cwd);
   }
   scanf(y);
 }
```

Ok i used the getcwd() and this is the message it gives me

chdir() error(): No such file or directory

How do i set the directory now.

Comment: User permissions? What OS are you running?

Comment: the magic portion? sorry couldn't resist with your username... ;)

Comment: You need to provide some more details about your program. Maybe you have a path hard-coded somewhere which is no longer valid on the new system.

Comment: I'm running Windows 7, previously it was XP on the other system.

Comment: Alright i tested this small code i wrote : #include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
                  
int main()
{
          int y;
    cout<<"Y ";cin>>y;
ofstream bss2;
bss2.open("expat.txt",ios::app);
bss2 << 2 ;
bss2.close();          

  
}
It prints the character propelry but nothing gets written onto the file when i click on the exectable, otherwise if i compile and run it from my C++ Environment it writes properly.

Comment: @Asterix: Add the necessary details into your question.

Comment: @Asterix: I notice that you have absolutely zero error checking in your code.

Comment: @Tomalak: Maybe it's only the minimum example, not the actual code.

Comment: Its not the actual code, wrote it to check whether the ofstream class was working properly.

Comment: @Dekei: A minimum example is _exactly_ what we want: one which demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best and easiest way is to give the full path of the output file rather than just the filename. That way, you can be sure where the file went, and not have to search for it everywhere. If you are using Windows, the output file might be somewhere in system32. But I could be wrong.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Just checked system32 and all the .txt files are sitting there. Now how do i change it ?

Comment: Unfortuantely there are well over 20 text files in each of the 50 c++ files that i'd have to change for it to work. What else can i do ?

Comment: If this answer helped you please do upvote. and accept this as the correct answer if it is.

Comment: have you tried saving the common directory as a string and just concatenating

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your working directory isn't being set correctly when you double-click on the file. If you can access a log, use `getcwd()` and log what it returns.

Comment: Ok i used the getcwd() and it tells me that there's no such file or working directory. How do i make it proper.

Comment: No, you used chdir("/tmp") and it told you that /tmp doesn't exist. If you're running on a Windows system you need to chdir("c:\\tmp"), assuming c:\tmp actually exists.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have Raymond Chen's psychic debugging powers yet, but I do know of a tool that may help you: [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645). Use it to see precisely which files your application is trying to write to, and why it fails.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your looking at the wrong location. The program will write the file to the current working directory, which may be different between when you double click on the executable and run from Dev-C++.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the working directory is likely incorrect.

If you create a shortcut to the .exe, you can set the working directory in the shortcut properties. Right-click on the shortcut, select "Properties", and change the "Start in" property.

Of course a better answer is to put the full path of the file into the filename string when you open it.

Comment: @Asterix, then I must conclude that you don't have the proper permissions to write to the directory. Windows 7 has added many restrictions on the places where you can create a file.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that Windows uses backslash, so try "\tmp" instead of "/tmp".

Also if all your files are in the same directory, then you can use find & replace and replace `open("` with `open("c:\\your_directory_here\`